# Forward a function call to another function without knowing the other function's arguments

Tags: php, php-5.2

In PHP 5.3, we can do it in this way.

```
function func() {
    return call_user_func_array('another_func', func_get_args());
}

function another_func($x, $y) { return $x + $y; }

echo func(1, 2); // print 3 in PHP 5.3
```

Note that `func` knows nothing about `another_func`'s argument list.

Is it possible to do this in PHP 5.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just store [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/func_get_args) to a variable then pass the variable to [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array):

```
function func() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    return call_user_func_array('another_func', $args);
}
```

[Example](http://ideone.com/4qob8)